# using the PHP mail function

Tags: php

I am using the PHP mail function to send my users emails about new features and updates. I can send an email and message no problem. But I would like to control who the message is from, well more who the Email Client says it is from.

For Example:

```
<?php

$to = "someone@gmail.com";
$subject = "Test";
$msg = "Hello there!";
$headers = "From: someone@shareit.me";

mail($to,$subject,$msg, $headers);

?>
```

In the mail client (Ie. Gmail) the user will see:

Someone    Test - Hello There

I would like to control the name of the sender via my headers. Is that possible?

So the email will be from someone@shareit.me but the name of the sender will be Shareit.

Thanks

Comment: Rule #1 in using `mail()` is **don't use `mail()`**. Use something like SwiftMailer that handles all of this with a sane API.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following headers: ([link to docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php))

```
$headers = "From: Shareit <someone@shareit.me>";
```

Answer (score 0):

`$headers = "From: Shareit <someone@shareit.me>";`

Try the above code.

Change the name from Shareit to the name of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

To use the `From` attribute inside of `headers` always remember to keep email addresses inside of these brackets: `<` and `>`

So now your email would be: `<someone@shareit.me>`

and your line would be: `$headers = "From: <someone@shareit.me>"`

or `"From: Shareit <someone@shareit.me>"`